# Firebird Embedded - Error while trying to open file

Tags: .net, nhibernate, firebird-embedded

I want to use Firebird 2.5. Embedded with NHibernate 3.2 in .NET 4.0 project. The work is great with firebird provider's code.  But when I try to configure NHibernate

```
Configuration = new Configuration().Configure();
```

**UPD:**

when I try to build session factory

```
Factory = Configuration.BuildSessionFactory();
```

the error occurs:

**I/O error during "CreateFile (open)" operation for file "C:\MYDB.FBD"
Error while trying to open file**

In the app.config everything looks fine

```
    <configSections>
    <section
        name="hibernate-configuration"
        type="NHibernate.Cfg.ConfigurationSectionHandler, NHibernate"
    />
</configSections>
<hibernate-configuration xmlns="urn:nhibernate-configuration-2.2">
    <session-factory>
            <property name="connection.driver_class">NHibernate.Driver.FirebirdClientDriver</property>
            <property name="connection.connection_string">
                Server=localhost;
                ServerType=1;
                Database=C:\MYDB.FBD;
                User=SYSDBA;Password=masterkey
            </property>
            <property name="show_sql">true</property>
            <property name="dialect">NHibernate.Dialect.FirebirdDialect</property>
            <property name="command_timeout">60</property>
            <property name="query.substitutions">true 1, false 0, yes 1, no 0</property>
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
<startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0" />
</startup>
```

Comment: Why you specify LOCALHOST for embedded database? Try to keep this property empty.

Comment: @AndreiK.  I've tried. But nothing has changed. Currently I'm looking for some info about implementing IConnectionProvider

Answer (score 0):

my guess is that firebird embedded uses the file exclusivly and when you open another session it tries to connect to the same file and throws.

one of the following helps:

- hold a global connection and do `OpenSession(globalConnection);`
- implement IConnectionProvider to handout a single database connection

Comment: I created separate project contains only configuration of nhibernate and get the same error... maybe nhibernate create several sessions at this stage inside?

Comment: have you implemented IConnectionProvider?

Comment: I trying to implement this. Thank you for your advice!

Comment: FB 2.5 embedded allows multiple simultaneous connections to the same database file.

Answer (score 0):

because I didn't see a solution I'll add what I've found - despit how old this post is:
You have to call `FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient.FbConnection.CreateDatabase(ConnectionString);` before using the database.

https://sourceforge.net/p/firebird/mailman/message/9316804/

Greetings
Juy Juka